# natbib: displaying author year and citation number

Tags: citing, natbib

I use natbib with the "numbers" option for citations and I would like to have a citation style that combines author-year and numeric.

For instance : "Author 1 et. al. [13] (2015)"

Is it possible with natbib only? It doesn't seem to be possible by default. I can define a new command to do it by combining citet and cite but I would like to avoid it as it is not native and makes me lose autocompletion on citations in my editor.

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of curiosity: *Why* would you want to state an entry's author, year, *and* the number-of-item-in-a-list all in one citation call-out? What information are you trying to provide to the reader? Use either an authoryear-style or a purely numeric-style citation call-out system. What is hybridizing the two styles supposed to achieve?

Comment: Hello, and thank you for replying. This is a legitimate enquiry; the answer is that I am writing a literature review and the chronology is somewhat important, this is why I want to provide the year to the reader. Otherwise I prefer the author - number style because I find it much easier to identify the item with the index in a long list of bibliography entries.

However I have also realised I don't need to provide all three elements each time I cite a paper, so I have settled for having a command to display the three only when I needed, and I otherwise provide the name and entry index.